# Manipulate lists in a pandas data frame column (e.g. divide by another column)

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance, fft

I have a pandas data frame with one column containing lists. I wish to divide each list element in each row by a scalar value in another column. In the following example, I wish to divide each element in a by b:

```
              a   b
0  [11, 22, 33]  11
1  [12, 24, 36]   2
2  [33, 66, 99]   3
```

Thus yielding the following result:

```
              a   b                   c
0  [11, 22, 33]  11     [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
1  [12, 24, 36]   2   [6.0, 12.0, 18.0]
2  [33, 66, 99]   3  [11.0, 22.0, 33.0]
```

**I can achieve this** by the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[[11,22,33],[12,24,36],[33,66,99]], "b" : [11,2,3]})

result = {"c":[]}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    result["c"].append([x / row["b"] for x in row["a"]])

df_c = pd.DataFrame(result)
df = pd.concat([df,df_c], axis="columns")
```

But explicit iteration over rows and collecting the result in a dictionary, converting it to a dataframe and then concatenation to the original data frame seems **very inefficient and inelegant**.

**Does anyone have a better solution?**

Thanks in advance and cheeers!

---

*PS*: In case you are wondering why I would store lists in a column: These are the resulting amplitudes of a Fourier-Transformation.

Why I don't use one column for each frequency?

1. Creating a new column for each frequency is horribly slow
2. With different sampling rates and FFT-window sizes in my project, there are multiple sets of frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip the two columns, divide each entry in col a with its corresponding entry in col b, through a combination of [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), and convert the iterator back into a list.

```
from itertools import product,starmap
from operator import floordiv
df['c'] = [list(starmap(floordiv,(product(num,[denom])))) 
           for num, denom in zip(df.a,df.b)]


        a           b       c
0   [11, 22, 33]    11  [1, 2, 3]
1   [12, 24, 36]    2   [6, 12, 18]
2   [33, 66, 99]    3   [11, 22, 33]
```

Alternatively, you could just use numpy array within the iteration:

```
df['c'] = [list(np.array(num)/denom) for num, denom in zip(df.a,df.b)]
```

Thanks to @jezrael for the suggestion - all of this might be unnecessary as Scipy has something for [FFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html).

Comment: not familiar with FFT. u could proffer that. gives me a chance to learn as well

Comment: It seems I am wrong, it seems output from FFT.+1, sorry

Comment: Clarification: I have no question about FFT. I was just explaining, why I would store lists in a data frame column, as I expected someone to question that design choice.

Comment: Your second alternative appealed most to me. Little benchmark: On an exemplary real dataset, it took ~4.9 seconds, whereas my clumsy attempt took ~121 seconds

Comment: thanks for the feedback; if somehow u find a much faster alternative, do share

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the lists to numpy arrays:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].apply(np.array) / df['b']
```

You will get `np.array`s in column c. If you really need lists, you will have to convert them back

```
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(list)
```

Comment: That is even more readable than the accepted answer, but with 6.1 seconds ever so slightly slower. Thanks a lot!